# Looping through an "ancestral" dictionary

Tags: python

I am fairly new to coding but am working on a database project. I need to loop through a dictionary that is composed of ID's and parent ID's, seeing if anywhere down the line a given ID is related to specific ancestor. I am having trouble looping through the dictionary properly.

This is what I have so far. I built a small sample dictionary to test on

```
List = []

d = {
     1: 2,
     2: 3,
     3: 4,
     4: 5,
     7: 10,
     99: 3,
     26: 8,
     9: 26
}


for key in d:
    x = key
    y = d[x]
    for i in d:
        while y != 3:
            if i == y:
                y = d[i]
        List.append(x)
        
print(List)
```

the idea is to follow an id back to a given ancestor, and if it matches, add the original ID to a list.

Any help is appreciated and I am eager to learn, so an explanation of what/why would also be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you “descended” from someone if that someone is *yourself*?

Obviously so.

Do you know who your father is?

If so, you are descended from someone if your father was descended from that person.

If not, then you cannot say you were descended from anyone.

Does all that make sense?

Let me write that in code:

```
def isDescendedFrom(child, forebearer, ancestry):
   # Are you “descended” from someone if that someone is *yourself*?
   if child == forebearer:
      #Obviously so.
      return True
   # Do you know who your father is?
   if child in ancestry:
     # If so, you are descended from someone 
     #   if your father was descended from that person.      
     return isDescendedFrom(ancestry[child], forebearer , ancestry)
   else:  
     # If not, then you cannot say you were descended from anyone.
     return False
```

See how that works?

You could re-write the above code as

```
def isDescendedFrom(child, forebearer, ancestry):
   return child == forebearer or 
       ((child in ancestry) and 
          isDescendedFrom(ancestry[child], forebearer , ancestry))
```

It might be less readable....

If you really wanted to win at CodeGolf:

```
def idf(c, p, a):
   return c and (c == p or idf(a.get(c), p, a))
```

Comment: I see where this is going, thank you!

Comment: How do i define child and forebearer at the call of this function? is Child my key value target and parent its corresponding value?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much. This is a solid start to what I would like to do and I think I can build the rest from here. And a valuable lesson! Just so you know, for whatever reason, the return statements in this script don't seem to be producing anything in the console.

Comment: @Nathan try printing it out explicitly: `print(idf(3, 5, d))`

Comment: yeah, I ended up just replacing the return comments with print statements, but just wanted to let you know for some reason the return statement dont generate outputs. I am well on my way now, thank you for all the help, I had a great time making small tweaks to this and learning python!

Comment: @Nathan — noooo!  Do not _replace_ the return statement!  They are not supposed to print out anything, that is not their role: they return things.  Invoke `idf` and print out whatever it returns.

Comment: @Nathan — and, you are more than welcome.  Look at your original version of the code and then at the final version.  Even ignoring that the first one did not work, the final is much more elegant: it expresses a clever yet simple approach to the problem; all of its edge-cases are explicit; and it is obviously how it works.  Because it is recursive, you have to watch for stack-overflows (ironically), but other than that, it’s really clean.

Comment: @Nathan — as an exercise, implement the same thing with an additional rule: a value is not its own ancestor; i.e. `idf(x, x, d)` is false for all `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the dict like this:

```
result = []
target = 3
for id_ in d:
    cur = id_
    while cur != 3:
        if cur not in d:
            break
        cur = d[cur]
    else:
        result.append(id_)
```

By the way, don't just name your variables with something like `d`, use something more meaningful to help others or your future self understand the code, for example: `id_to_parent_id`.

Comment: Thank you, noted and I will try to be more specific. You guys rock